# Close popup/dropdown on focusout (keyboard control)

Tags: javascript, keyboard, focus, accessibility

I'm trying to make an accessible popup/dropdown like the example on [W3's website](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/flyout/#flyoutnavkbfixed). If you click on the keyboard users approach 1 menu, and then tab into the Space Bears menu item, pressing enter will open the menu. Then, if you press tab, you go through the menu. Once the focus is out of the menu, the dropdown automatically disappears. This is the functionality that I'm trying to emulate. I got the rest working, but their JavaScript snippet doesn't explain how to hide the popup on focusout.

I got the following solution of my own, which uses a timeout. The timeout is there, because without it, the activeElement is the body. I need to wait that short bit for the focus to be on an element. I feel like there could be a more reliable approach, rather than relying on a timeout, though.

Note that I called it a modal in my code, but it's likely not actually a "modal". This was just what I named it.

```js
$('.js-modal *').on('focusout', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var is_in_modal = $(document.activeElement).closest('.js-modal').length;

      if (!is_in_modal) {
        close_modals();
      }
    }, 10);

  });
```

Comment: Why not use a form control to allow closing? I suspect the behavior will be surprising to most users and I cannot see how that scheme will be accessible. It might be helpful to look at the aria authoring practices docs on modal https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#dialog_modal

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of something that disappears automatically when you go out of it is a bad idea.
You'd better switch to a more classic solution, like a true modal, as already well described by the other answer.

It's a bad idea because it's confusing. 
Let's imagine this scenario: we have five elements 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. 3 and 4 are initially hidden and appear when 2 is focused.
I'm initially on element 1:

1. I press tab and go to element 2. Element 3 and 4 appear, but since I'm blind, I may not have noticed it at all.
2. I press tab again. I go to element 3
3. I press tab. I go to element 4
4. I press again tab. I go to element 5. Elements 3 and 4 disappear but again, I may not have noticed it.
5. OK, well, I finally want to go back to element 3, so I press Shift+Tabb. **I expect to land on element 4, but went on 2 instead**. Where is element 3 ?

I hope that with this little scenario, you understand the problem. If I'm not aware at all that elements appear or disappear, I find elements in a different order than I expect.
If at that moment I don't understand the logic and don't find back the element 3, great are the chances that I leave the site forever.

---

You aren't convainced ?

I imagine you have been told to do that to have the same logic for keyboard users than with mouse users.
With the mouse, you click on the menu, it opens, but closes as soon as you leave its area.

Note that it's also a poor idea in terms of accessibility, because you require the user to be quite precise. Following precise paths with the mouse isn't' always easy, especially for elder people or people with movement difficulties.
For that reason, we usually recommand to no longer use menus like that, and change their behavior to make them **disappear only when clicking outside of it**. So, mouse users with some movement difficulties have all their time and freedom to select what they want to select.

For keyboard users, that's kind of the same thing. If I'm blind, I expect focusable elements to always have the same tab order, and expect changes in that order only when I make a conscient action like press enter to expand/collapse a menu.
If I'm sighted and use the keyboard for whatever reason, I don't expect elements to appear or disappear on screen when just pressing tab.

---

Still not convainced ?

So ask yourself another question: how do I use your interface with a smarphone ?
With a touch device, there's no real focus, as well as there's no real mouseover, until you click on a precise element to interact with it. It's problematic, isn't it ?
You don't have at all these notions, so you must react on clicks. You don't have choice, and that's good.

Comment: In your example, I don't make elements 3 and 4 appear automatically on focus. They only appear when you press enter over element 2, so I think the user would have a greater understanding of how things work. They also appear on hover, for mouse users.

Comment: The following website is a perfect example of what I'm trying to achieve (their navigation menu drop downs). While tabbing, you press enter to open a drop down. The drop down automatically disappears on focus out. https://www.vincenzosonline.com/ . Maybe modal was the wrong word for me to use. It's just that I'm applying this to other parts of my website that behave more like true modals, as well.

Answer (score 0):

> automatically disappears when the users uses keyboard/TAB navigation to focus out of it.

This is the exact opposite of the behaviour of a modal.

You should trap focus inside your modal and it should close with the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key and via a close button (accessible via keyboard).

[This article is a good starting place to learn about Modals](https://bitsofco.de/accessible-modal-dialog/), although I disagree with the method for point 5 "While Open, Prevent Tabbing to Outside the Dialog" - this should also include using `aria-hidden` on every element outside the modal as otherwise screen reader users can end up outside the modal (as they may navigate via links or headings etc.) when they shouldn't be.

**Final thought** - are you sure you need a modal? There may be a better pattern you could use if the above does not apply to your use case.

Comment: Maybe I'm using the wrong term here. I'm basically describing a drop down menu from a navigation, but I'm also using the same principle elsewhere in the website. The drop down does not have a close button (as most don't), but the other modals do have close buttons. Perhaps the menu drop down should behave like I'm requesting, but the other modals on the site should not?

Comment: perhaps close this question or heavily edit it, there is a vast difference between a menu like you describe (and the example given in the comments below @QuentinC's answer) and a modal. Also the menu for the site you gave as an example is also not very accessible because you are forced to tab past every item, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59668131/multi-level-dropdown-menu-that-is-keyboard-accessible-for-wcag-ada-compliance/59668621#59668621 OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59328987/making-menu-drop-down-on-focus-for-accessibility/59333988#59333988 for some ideas.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I'll call it a popup/dropdown instead. I actually did come across, and followed, that W3C article. The menus on the w3 site function exactly how I'd like mine to. When tabbing into "space bears", click enter. That brings up the popup. Then tab through the popup. As soon as the tab focus leaves the popup, that popup closes. W3 doesn't explain how they did that in their snippet, and that's what I'm trying to emulate.

Comment: `el.addEventListener("blur", function(event) {
    timer2 = setTimeout(function () {
     var opennav = document.querySelector("#flyoutnavkbbtn .has-submenu.open")
     if (opennav) {
      opennav.className = "has-submenu";
      opennav.querySelector('a').setAttribute('aria-expanded', "false");
      opennav.querySelector('button').setAttribute('aria-expanded', "false");
     }
    }, 10);
   });` This is the code that causes it to close, they check if the `open` class is applied and if so remove it

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm surprised they use a timer too...there's gotta be a better way.